# Can't catch Throwable - JPA + Glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish

I was given to work on an ear project that runs on **Glassfish** and works with **JPA** + **mysql**.
Now, on the glassfish log I get tons of massive exceptions, for example (I shortened the stack trace):

```
[2017-04-05T13:24:40,584] [http-listener-1(5)] WARN  No projects were found
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'project_version_id_version' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT project_version_id_version, project_version_id_project FROM anthillprodashboard.project_version WHERE (project_version_id_project = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="ProjectVersion.findAllByProject" referenceClass=ProjectVersion sql="SELECT project_version_id_version, project_version_id_project FROM anthillprodashboard.project_version WHERE (project_version_id_project = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:382) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar:?]
    ... A lot more lines ...
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy254.getAllVersionsForProject(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at **com.valor.anthillprodashboard.ui.page.AdminPage.generateVersionDualList(AdminPage.java:245)** [AdminPage.class:?]
    ... A lot more lines ...
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar:?]
    ... 116 more]]
```

Now, what's interesting is that on line 245, like the stack trace suggests, I have this piece of code:

```
try {
     versionsForProject = this.dataAccessFacade.getAllVersionsForProject(this.currentProjectForVersion);
}
catch (Throwable e){
    versionsForProject = null;
}
```

Which suppose to handle every possible Exception/Error out there.

So, my question is how or who exactly is giving me these exceptions? And how can I handle them?

Comment: It's possible EclipseLink's own logging system is sending that to the Glassfish loggers before rethrowing the exception to you.

Comment: @SteveSmith no, couldn't find any exits inside the whole project.

Comment: @coladict The logger that is being used by the project is: org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.
Oh, I see. Is there a way to prevent it? Cause the code doesn't continue to run after that line.

Comment: The only way for it not to continue would be a the thread or application exiting. Put an unconditional log message after the try-catch block and see what happens.

Comment: I already have a log message after the try-catch block, and it doesn't get there.

Comment: Catching this is not the right way, just fix your code!